# MySQL DROP DATABASE Privilege?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how can I revoke only the `DROP DATABASE` privilege, without revoking `DROP TABLE` privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign the DROP privilege for the individual tables, not for the entire database.

Comment: That sounds like a plan, but it would (in my opinion) be quite an oversight if this is the only way.

Comment: Agreed, it **is** an oversight! MySQL should make the distinction between `DROP DATABASE` and `DROP TABLE` (and probably `DROP own DATABASE` and `DROP own TABLE`). If you feel like coding, feel free to submit a patch to the developers :)

Comment: The report, yes. The patch, no. Have a go at it? ;)