# Create user with Drop privilege for just tables Not DB

Tags: mysql, privileges

Can someone help me with privileges here. I need to create a user that can DROP tables within databases but cannot DROP the databases?
MySQL DB version:5.0.95

Comment: granting DROP TABLE on a database allows the user to drop the database.  Eg, GRANT DROP ON TABLE DB1.* TO USERNAME allows USERNAME to drop the database DB1.

Comment: found this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030772/mysql-drop-database-privilege)

Answer (score 0):

If he can drop tables, he can simply enter the query `DROP TABLE *;` effectively dropping the contents of the database. There is no plus to allowing a user to drop only tables, and thus I don't think there is a way to do so.